# How to run a task before and another task after assembleRelease on Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have two distinct tasks that do version control for my App:

**Task A** - Checkout the "master" branch on git, then merge the "develop" branch on "master;

**Task B** - Checkout back the "develop" branch

How do I run "**task A**" before task "**assembleRelease**" and "**task B**" after "**assembleRelease**"?

If I run the three tasks manually, everything runs fine, but I wanted a way to run a flow running just one task.

```
taskA -> assembleRelease -> taskB
```

I tried with the options:

```
assembleRelease.configure { dependsOn(taskA) }
taskB.mustRunAfter(assembleRelease)
```

But always get:

```
"Could not get unknown property 'assembleRelease' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project."
```

Answer (score 0):

So, i basically found the solution:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
        task.dependsOn('taskA')
    }
    if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
        task.doLast {
            taskB
        }
    }
}
```